# Установка oracle xe database: не проходит configure (Error ORA-01034: ORACLE not available)

Tags: oracle, centos, rpm, oracle18c

Устанавливаю версию 18c из rpm на Centos7. Установка проходит гладко, а вот сконфигурировать и запустить не получается:

```
[oracle@d891e55715d8 bin]$ sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure
Specify a password to be used for database accounts. Oracle recommends that the password entered should be at least 8 characters in length, contain at least 1 uppercase character, 1 lower case character and 1 digit [0-9]. Note that the same password will be used for SYS, SYSTEM and PDBADMIN accounts:
Confirm the password:
Configuring Oracle Listener.
Listener configuration succeeded.
Configuring Oracle Database XE.
Enter SYS user password: 
***
Enter SYSTEM user password: 
****
Enter PDBADMIN User Password: 
***
Prepare for db operation
7% complete
Copying database files
8% complete
[WARNING] ORA-00821: Specified value of sga_target 1536M is too small, needs to be at least 2416M
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

9% complete
[FATAL] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

29% complete
100% complete
[FATAL] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

7% complete
0% complete
Look at the log file "/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/XE/XE3.log" for further details.

Database configuration failed. Check logs under '/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca'.
```

Сталкивался кто-нибудь с подобным?

Comment: А как вы отреагировали на сообщение: _ORA-00821: Specified value of sga_target 1536M is too small, needs to be at least 2416M_?

Comment: @0xdb в этом и дело. Указывал в конфиге размер около 4 гб, но установщик этого будто не видит. Чтобы я не пытался править в конфиге всегда ловил эту ошибку

Comment: Попробуйте удалить sga_target  из конфигурации вообще, он устарел и должен больше использоваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сталкивался. 
При конфигурирований БД автоматом параметр processes выставляла в значение больше 3000, это много (возможно из за большого количества ядер или ОЗУ так перерасчитывает).

Удалите БД /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c delete

В /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/assistants/dbca/templates/XE_Database.dbc в теге InitParams пропишите опцию < initParam name="processes" value="800" />

Запустить снова конфигурирование /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure